# How to optimize time to obtain large data set?

Tags: export, list-manipulation, data

I would like to generate a set of data of matrix of size 1000 x 1000 x 1000 in a region defined by 0 outside the sphere of radius r=100 centered in the coordinate (500, 500, 500), and number 1 inside the sphere.

```
n = 1000;(*Matrix dimension*)
f = Compile[{i, j, k},If[(i-500)^2 + (j - 500)^2 + (k - 500)^2 <= (10)^2, 1, 0]];
ic = ParallelTable[f[N@i, N@j, N@k], {i, n}, {j, n}, {k, n}];
```

Next, to apply Fast Fourier Transform to data.

```
fftshift[dat_?ArrayQ, k : (_Integer?Positive | All) : All] := Module[{dims = Dimensions[dat]}, 
   RotateRight[dat,If[k === All, Quotient[dims, 2],Quotient[dims[[k]], 2] UnitVector[Length[dims], k]]]];
ict = Table[fftshift@ic[[i]], {i, Length[ic]}];
```

Finally to export the data.

```
Export["ic50.mat", ict]
```

However, the time to conclude the process is huge.

How to optimize this to reduce run time?

Comment: I don't know what you mean to do with the Fast Fourier Transform. Your code does not involve any. Though you should be able to use the command `Fourier` for that. Applied to a multidimensional tensor, it applies FFT to _each_ of its slots.

Comment: @xzczd thank you. I was looking for something like this code.

Answer (score 3):

The fastest solution for the array `ci` that I found so far is this one:

```
cf = Compile[{{x, _Real}, {y, _Real, 1}, {z, _Real, 1}, {r, _Real}},
   Block[{r2},
    r2 = r r - x;
    Table[
     If[Compile`GetElement[y, i] + Compile`GetElement[z, j] <= r2, 1.,0.],
     {i, 1, Length[y]},
     {j, 1, Length[z]}
     ]
    ],
   CompilationTarget -> "C",
   RuntimeAttributes -> {Listable},
   Parallelization -> True,
   RuntimeOptions -> "Speed"
   ];

n = 1000.;
r = 100.;
x = (Range[1., n, 1.] - n/2.)^2;
ci = cf[x, x, x, r];
```

It takes about 3 seconds on my Quad Core machine (a dated Haswell). The idea is to perform many computations only once for the vector `x` and to exploint parallelization in `Compile` enabled by `Listable`. The output has size 8 GB, so performance depends critically on the available RAM. My machine has only 16 GB, so I run into heavy swapping if I generate `ci` and then do some further manipulations with it.